# How to delay an ARM Cortex M0+ for n cycles, without a timer?

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m

I want to delay an ARM Cortex M0+ for n cycles, without using a timer, with the smallest possible code size.  (I think this mandates use of assembly.)

A delay of 0 cycles is simple no code.
A delay of 1 cycle is a single NOP.
A delay of 2 cycles is two NOPs.

At what point is it (code-size) efficient to start looping?

How many cycles does the tightest possible loop take?  What is the setup time?

---

Post answer notes:

The following C code:

```
register unsigned char counter = 100;
while (counter-- > 0) {
  asm("");
}
```

when compiled with gcc and -O3 gives:

```
    mov r3, #100
.L5:
    sub r3, r3, #1
    uxtb    r3, r3
    cmp r3, #0
    bne .L5
```

This either illustrates that there is still purpose in hand-coding ARM assembly, or (much more likely) that the C code above is not the best way of convey to the compiler what I want to do.

Comments?

Comment: Using `char` here slows the loop down. If instead you use `int`, the `uxtb` instruction will disappear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code is going to depend on exactly what *n* is, and whether it needs to be dynamically variable, but given [the M0+ core's instruction timings](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0484c/CHDCICDF.html), establishing bounds for a particular routine is pretty straightforward.

For the smallest possible (6-byte) complete loop with a fixed 8-bit immediate counter:

```
   movs  r0, #NUM    ;1 cycle
1: subs  r0, r0, #1  ;1 cycle
   bne   1b          ;2 if taken, 1 otherwise
```

with `NUM=1` we get a minimum of 3 cycles, plus 3 cycles for every extra loop up to `NUM=255` at 765 cycles (of course, you could have 2^32 iterations from `NUM=0`, but that seems a bit silly). That puts the lower bound for a loop being practical at about 6 cycles. With a fixed loop it's easy to pad NOPs (or even nested loops) inside it to lengthen each iteration, and before/after to align to a non-multiple of the loop length. If you can arrange for a number of iterations to be ready in a register before you need to start waiting, then you can lose the initial `mov` and have pretty much any multiple of 3 or more cycles, minus one. If you need single-cycle resolution for a variable delay, the initial setup cost is going to be somewhat higher to correct for the remainder (a computed branch into a NOP sled is what I'd do for that)

I'm assuming that if you're at the point of cycle-critical timing you've already got interrupts off (otherwise throw in another cycle somewhere for `CPSID`), and that you don't have any bus wait states adding extra cycles to instruction fetches.

As for trying to do it in C: the fact that you have to hack in an empty `asm` to keep the "useless" loop from being optimised away is a tip-off. The abstract C machine has no notion of "instructions" or "cycles" so there is simply no way to reliably express this in the language. Trying to rely on particular C constructs to compile to suitable instructions is extremely fragile - change a compiler flag; upgrade the compiler; change some distant code which affects register allocation which affects instruction selection; etc. - pretty much anything could change the generated code unexpectedly, so I'd say hand-coded assembly is the *only* sensible approach for cycle-accurate code.

Comment: Thanks that's really useful.  I'm (run-time) generating code (containing only GPIO changes, cycle-accurate delays and a return) into RAM and calling it.

Comment: Dynamically generating a fixed loop like this should be fairly simple - take a template based on `movs rN #0...`, logical-or the loop count into the lsb of the first instruction and add 0-2 NOPs after for padding. The code _generation_ should definitely happen in C for sanity, but I think the template itself needs hand-coding as per my edit.

Answer (score 5):

The shortest ARM loop that I can think of goes like:

```
mov r0, #COUNT
L:
subs r0, r0, #1
bnz L
```

Since I don't have the device in question, no idea about timing. Those are core dependent.